# How to use UseStaticFiles in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I can't find many proper Core 1.0 tutorials yet, but when I google the method name, I get umpteen examples that say to include in `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Yet I get compile errors that neither method exists on `app`, which is type `IApplicationBuilder`. Are these calls no longer required, or named totally different, or set somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your project.json make sure you have a reference

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

in RC2 that will likely need to change to Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

then you should be able to use

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to add

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
```

in your `project.json` here `"1.0.0"` is the version you want to use

Comment: New version is `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"`. Notice it's not `AspNet` anymore, but `AspNetCore`.

Comment: @youen yes you are correct when I have answered it was `AspNet` now I updated answer using new

Comment: use app.UseFileServer(); which will add both app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(); services.

Answer (score 8):

Now with release 1.0 the correct reference will be:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to Asp.Net Core Web API project using `.csproj` rather than `project.json`, you can install the package using Nuget Package Manager (search for `microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles`).

Answer (score 0):

Up till today it is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles: 1.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

You must change Target framework in your project properties to .Net Core 2.0:

[image]